# float and double constant comparing

Tags: c++, double, equals-operator

From http://www.cprogramming.com/tips/tip/difference-between-float-and-double:

> In c++ any value like 4.12 is treated as a double by default. 
>   Comparing floats and doubles can be a tricky business because of the
>   difference in precision leading to minute errors. For example:

```
float a = 4.12;

if(a == 4.12)
{
    cout << "hello";
}
else
{
    cout << "bye";
}
```

> This will show you the output as "bye 4.12"
>
> Why?
>
> Because by default 4.12 is a double (such as in the if statement or 
>   in the assignment to our variable), but storing it in a float it loses 
>   some precision, and so comparing then comparing a double with a float 
>   lead to microscopic changes in the precision of the number--remember 
>   that floats and doubles are not precise.
>
> Two lessons here: one is that floating point numbers shouldn't be compared directly most of the time, and the other is that the default size and type of a hard-coded floating point number is double.

The thing is 'you should not do comparing float variable and double constant'.

So my question is that comparing float variable and float constant followed by 'f' is ok?

Something like this.

```
if(a == 4.12f)
```

Comment: Er what's your question?

Comment: Are you asking whether comparing a float constant with a float variable that was initialized with a double constant (identical to the float constant except for the f) will always evaluate to equal? If so I think that is a reasonable question.

Comment: @samgak Yes, exactly. Sorry for my poor english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> comparing float variable and float constant followed by 'f' is ok?

It's still dangerous.  Unlike your `float`/`double` example which may well fail for every possible value of `a`, there is actually one value of `a` for which `a == 4.12f` will be `true`, but depending on how you set `a` it may not match `4.12f` even when you expect it to.  For example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main()
{
    float f = 4.14;
    f -= 0.01;
    f -= 0.01;
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << (f == 4.12f) << '\n';
}
```

On [ideone.com here](http://ideone.com/mN7ahF) this outputs:

```
false
```

The Standard does guarantee that the closest representation will be used in certain circumstances, so if you directly assign `float a = 4.12f;` then afterwards `a == 4.12f` will necessarily be `true`, and § 26.5.1.4 guarantees that if you stream out `a` and stream the text back in to another `float` they will compare equals afterwards.

Anyway, if you feel you must depend on something like this, check the Standard/docs for the specific usage you're contemplating.